Enabling NRVO when forwarding a function's result via template function
When forwarding a function's result via template function, I encountered different behaviour regarding utilization of "named return value optimization (NRVO)"  for clang and gcc. Here a code snippet:
Foo provideFooAsTemporary() 
{
    return Foo{};
}

template <typename TFn>
auto forwardA(TFn &&fn) 
{
    auto result = fn();
    return result;
}

template <typename TFn>
auto forwardB(TFn &&fn) -> decltype(fn()) 
{
    auto result = fn();
    return result;
}

Foo fooA = forwardA(provideFooAsTemporary);  
Foo fooB = forwardB(provideFooAsTemporary);

Here my observations (also see godbolt example):

gcc 14.1: Avoids any move operations for both forwardA and forwardB.

clang 18.0.1: Avoids moving only for forwardB, but a move operation occurs for forwardA.


I would have expected that forwardA triggers NRVO also for clang.
Here my questions:

What exactly is the difference between forwardA and forwardB? Why does the specified trailing return type make a difference?

Is there a simpler way to enable NRVO for clang than what is shown in forwardB?



Surprisingly this is a known issue in Clang's current implementation of NRVO:
If a function template uses a deduced return type (i.e. auto or decltype(auto)), then NRVO is not applied for any instantiation of that function template.
See e.g. the bug reports

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/95280
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58789
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/43191
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/42351
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/38674

and probably more others.
As far as I can see, there isn't really any reason that application of NRVO should depend on whether or not the return type is explicitly specified. This seems to be a limitation of the current implementation approach.
However, from a conformance point of view, NRVO is never guaranteed to happen and a compiler is always free to choose not to apply it. It can't be forced to do it.
